# gulp compile SCSS/SASS breaks on valid color value

Tags: css, sass

I've got this code. Which works in chrome dev-tools

```
p {
    color: #00000070;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 98;
}
```

and when I try to compile it i get this error

```
[19:36:38] Using gulpfile ~/job/fello/gulpfile.js
[19:36:38] Starting 'sass'...
Error in plugin 'sass'
Message:
    wp-content/themes/fellose/styles/layouts/_mypages.scss
Error: Invalid CSS after "                      color:": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "#00000070;"
        on line 462 of wp-content/themes/fellose/styles/layouts/_mypages.scss
>>                      color: #00000070;
------------^
```

If I put any other value like `#000000` or `black` it works. I think it has somehting to do with me putting the last bits for the opacity.

Answer (score 1):

color code has only 3 (#000) or 6 (#000000) digit value. so you have to add only 3 or 6 digit and if you want to add opacity then define color in `rgba(0,0,0,0.6)`;

first three number are used for color and last float value is used for opacity.

Comment: so `#00000070` would equal to `rgba(0,0,0,0.7)`. Do you know why it works on chrome dev tools?

Comment: `#00000070` would equal `rgba(0,0,0,0.44)`. The numbers following the hashtag are hexadecimal (base 16). The max, `FF`, would be 16*15 + 1*15 = 255. `70` is 16*7 + 1*0 = 112. And 112/255 is ~0.44.

Answer (score 1):

Color codes with more than 6 digits are not supported in CSS/SCSS. I'm not sure why chrome dev-tools allow that.

Just use 
`color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);` 
instead.

If you want to add opacity to other colors, but you don't feel like translating them into rgb, you can also use the scss variable there:

```
$my-color: pink;

color: rgba($my-color,0.5);
```